# Is there a recovery option to start service regardless of dependant service state?

Tags: windows

Critical services ServiceB, ServiceC and ServiceD must be started after non-critical ServiceA (ServiceA monitors B,C and D but is not critical for operation).

If there are any issues starting ServiceA we still need to start B,C and D. Otherwise we always want to start ServiceA first. We would prefer not to stop B,C or D if A crashes(is stopped during operation)

All services are set to Automatic start. (We cannot use delayed start for B,C and D as the timing is not suitable and we don't want to change default 2 minutes for other delayed services)

Dependancies have been set on a service B,C and D so that they will always start the requisite service if it is not running. These will stop if ServiceA is stopped.

Command below for setting dependancy:

```
sc config ServiceB depend= ServiceA
```

We are exploring the system for recovery options that will start B,C and D regardless if A will not start after a number of attempts.

If it is impossible to configure through SC.exe or by configuring Windows 10 then we can revert back to using a start-up script or custom service control app as I have both built already but would prefer this cleaner option of configuring the OS.

Are there groups of services that could be configured with a different delayed start wait value?

Any suggestions or edits appreciated. TIA

Comment: Just a note, I see this appears more like a windows OS question but I am developing a VBScript solution currently to achieve which I will post if the above is not possible. It also needs to be done programatically for automation.

Comment: How do you know if A has hanged or not? It may still look like it is running

Comment: I don't but the people monitoring the dashboard will get alerts and open tickets for investigation. A is third-party but B, C and D are our own so we don't want to impact our own system to accomodate. The VBScript answer below handles it better than expected but I did have to elevate to allow for proper service control of the third party service.

Comment: The other option would be to contact the developers of A and see if they could hook into our services while they are running, rather than needing to sequence them but this might not be feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we already run a start-up script I've put this together quickly. It's not ideal and a little inefficent but it does work. Setting ServiceB, C and D to manual start and using this to start them may achieve the desired result without needing the dependancies above.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

If Not ServiceAction("ServiceA", -1) = "RUNNING" Then 
    'Stop the services if they are running
    ServiceAction "ServiceB", 0
    ServiceAction "ServiceC", 0
    ServiceAction "ServiceD", 0
    'Start the services in sequence
    ServiceAction "ServiceA", 1
    ServiceAction "ServiceB", 1
    ServiceAction "ServiceC", 1
    ServiceAction "ServiceD", 1
End If

Function ServiceAction(service_name, service_action)
    'Start Service
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service Where Name ='" & service_name & "'")
    For Each objService in colListOfServices
        If service_action = -1 Then 
            ServiceAction = UCase(objService.State)
        ElseIf service_action = 1 Then 
            ServiceAction = objService.StartService()
        ElseIf service_action = 0 Then
            ServiceAction = objService.StopService()
        End If
    Next
    'For debugging
    WScript.Echo "WMI CODE: "&ServiceAction
End Function
```